# Why does this guy have a 100% accept rate displayed?

Tags: support, specific-question

Why does [this joker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387417/ankur-mukherjee) have a 100% accept rate?

His profile is full of unaccepted questions, and I'm very sure they weren't all accepted in the past 24 hours, and happened to get unaccepted by him since.

Am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the Stack Overflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/):

> The following rules are used in the calculation:
>
> - Questions must not be community wiki.
> - Questions must not be closed.
> - Questions must be more than 3 days old.
> - Questions must have at least 1 answer.
> - There must be at least four eligible questions as determined by
>   the above rules, otherwise the
>   statistic will not appear.

The user's open questions are not more than 3 days old, and the earliest question the user asked was closed.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the question age! This guy is *really* in a hurry to build a SMS application, and he has *no* idea how to do it. :) Thanks!